# Do I have to reboot my server after updating the htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, debian

I made several changes to my htaccess file. Mostly to edit the expires values:

```
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresDefault "access plus 7200 seconds" 
 ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"  
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"  
 ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"  
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"  
 AddType image/x-icon .ico 
 ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 1 month"  
 ExpiresByType image/icon "access plus 1 month"  
 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 month"  
 ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month" 
 ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"  
 ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 7200 seconds"
```

When I run [PageSpeed](http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) on my website, the changes are not taken into account.

Do I have to reboot my server for these changes to be applied ?

Answer (score 0):

If you change `.htaccess`, not. If you do similar changes in the web server configuration then you need to reload `apache`. But beware that these headers might be cached so you might need to wait a bit before re-trying.